# How to show success message in popup modal after submitting the form in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, jquery

here i did this to show popup modal

```
<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">

    <form class="form contact"
          action="<?= $block->getUrl("popup/action/index") ?>"
          id="contact-form"
          method="post"
          data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
          data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Get in touch')) ?></span></legend>
            <br/>
            <div class="field note no-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Simply fill in your details and enquiry below and one of our team will be in touch as soon as possible.')) ?></div>
            <div class="field firstname required">
                <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your Name')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="name" id="name" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Name')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="field emailaddress required">
                <label class="label" for="emailaddress"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer email address')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field mobile">
                <label class="label" for="mobile"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone number')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="mobile" id="mobile" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone number')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field postcode">
                <label class="label" for="postcode"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer postcode')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="postcode" id="postcode" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Customer postcode')) ?>"
                           class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field enquiry required">
                <label class="label" for="enquiry"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Enquiry')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Enquiry')) ?>"
                        class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="field extension required">
                <input type='hidden' name="extension" id="extension-name"
                       class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" id='customer-contact' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>"
                        class="action submit primary">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function (
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                
               buttons: []
                    
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $(".demo-banner .pagebuilder-button-primary").on('click', function () {
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

my controller

```
<?php
namespace Test\Email\Controller\Index;
 
use Zend\Log\Filter\Timestamp;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
 
class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   /**
        * Recipient email config path
        */
        const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'contact/email/recipient_email';
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
        */
        protected $_transportBuilder;

        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
        */
        protected $inlineTranslation;

        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
        */
        protected $scopeConfig;

        /**
        * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
        */
        protected $storeManager;
        /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
        */
        protected $_escaper;

        /**
        * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
        * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
        * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
            \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
            $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
            $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        }

        /**
         * Post user question
         *
         * @return void
         * @throws \Exception
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            //$resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
            //print_r($post);
            //die("hello");
            if (!$post) {
                $this->_redirect('/');
                return;
            }

            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

            try {
                $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                $postObject->setData($post);
                $error = false;

                $sender = [
                    'name' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['name']),
                    'email' => $this->_escaper->escapeHtml($post['email']),
                ];

                $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE; 
                $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('custom_email_template') // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
                    ->setTemplateOptions(
                        [
                            'area' => 'frontend',                    
                            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId() 
                        ]
                    )
                    ->setTemplateVars([
                        'name' => $post['name'],
                        'email' => $post['email']
                    ])
                    ->setFrom($sender)
                    ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                    ->addTo('mani@gmail.com','owner')
                   
                    ->getTransport();

                    $transport->sendMessage();
                    $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                        __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
                    );
                    //$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
                    $this->_redirect('/');
                    return;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.'.$e->getMessage())
                );
                //$resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

                $this->_redirect('/');
                return;
            }
        }
}
```

after submitting the form i am sending email to admin with customer details
Now i need to show success message in popup itself after submitting the form. And how to recive email after submiting the form without page load and how to send from details to my controller.
Iam new to js,jquery.any help can be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: You need to submit the form via AJAX and return appropriate success or error message from controller in JSON format and show that response message in custom div inside form.

Comment: Hi @LokeshNaik , could please explain with an example i would better understand. Thanku

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/webkul/magento2_ajax_contact_form